# How to set up jest typescripts tests to run in debug mode using vscode

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, jestjs

I have created a react app by following https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter

Is there a guide or link that provide simple and easy setup to debug tests written in jest and enzymes in vscode?  I have come across bits and pieces and none is working so far.

If I click on run, I get the error:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the latest `create-react-app` (2.1.5) and `react-scripts-ts` (3.1.0), create a `.vscode` directory at the root of your project and add the following `launch.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug CRA Tests",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts-ts",
      "args": [
        "test",
        "--runInBand",
        "--no-cache",
        "--no-watch",
        "--env=jsdom"
      ],
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then start the VSCode debugger using the `Debug CRA Tests` configuration.